# Express: server.listen(). Why do I have to define something already defined?

Tags: express

Here is a question about Express.js.

I've noticed that this code below is not working:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const http = require('http');
const app = require('./app');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT);
const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen();
```

To make it work I have to add one argument to server.listen():

```
server.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

But I don't get why, as I have already declared that server use app, and app is declared with a port set to process.env.PORT. So, why I have to say it again? As I would think that server.listen() should be enough.

I am a newbie and I guess there is something obvious, but right now, I don't get it.

Here is the content of app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use('/', (_,res) => {
    const message = {
        message: "Hello World!"
    };

res.status(200).json(message);})

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Please show us the content of app.js file. CreateServer function parameter is a callback that will be called when any request comes to your server. In order listen for incoming requests you have to start your server by calling listen method of server object. Not sure how you have defined listening functionality in your app.js file.

Comment: I've added the content of app.js. I thought that to have set the port for app to process.env.PORT was enough indeed. `app.set('port', process.env.PORT)`

Comment: thats just a place where you can save key value pairs. you can get the value somewhere else with `app.get("port")` it has nothing to do with setting the port

Comment: Yep `app.set()` is just store key value pairs. http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#app.set.

Comment: ah thank you very much. It's was really misleading. So, indeed, here, to make this work, delcare this 'app.set()`is just useless, it can work without it. And I've just checked, indeed, it's working... thanks !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is:

The server is not set up twice in the code mentioned in the question.

The confusion comes from app.set() which is not the equivalent of server.listen().

App.set() define a variable that we can call with app.get().